# Image loaded wrong by opencv

Tags: python, opencv

Disaster!
[image]

As you can see, the image isn't quite loaded correctly. The original:
[image]

The code:

```
import cv2
import imutils
a=imutils.url_to_image("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png", readFlag=-1)
cv2.imshow("goog", a)
cv2.waitKey()
```

The implementation of url_to_image in imutils:

```
def url_to_image(url, readFlag=cv2.IMREAD_COLOR):
    # download the image, convert it to a NumPy array, and then read
    # it into OpenCV format
    resp = urlopen(url)
    image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
    image = cv2.imdecode(image, readFlag)

    # return the image
    return image
```

I also tried readFlag=cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED, but that didn't do the trick either.

please send help

Answer (score 1):

alright gang we did it

so I tried another version of displaying:

```
plt.figure("Correct")
plt.imshow(imutils.opencv2matplotlib(a))
plt.show()
```

[image]

No luck it would appear. But then, looking into the  opencv2matplotlib source, we find:

```
def opencv2matplotlib(image):
    # OpenCV represents images in BGR order; however, Matplotlib
    # expects the image in RGB order, so simply convert from BGR
    # to RGB and return
    return cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

Aha, but we have 4 channel color (alpha), so by common sense we need cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGBA not cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB!!

Testing this theory:

```
plt.figure("Correct")
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(a, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGBA))
plt.show()
```

We get...

[image]

Whoop dee doop!

Comment: why don't you use urllib

Comment: I have a solution to this. Do you still need it?

Comment: you won't use matplotlib in that case. rather you'll be using simple imshow(img) to display the image

Comment: ? urllib is used. urlopen is under namespace urllib.request

also, cv2.imdecode needs to be called with flag of -1 or it doesn't even write to file correctly

Answer (score 0):

```
# import the necessary packages
import numpy as np
import urllib
import cv2

def url_to_image(url):
    # download the image, convert it to a NumPy array, and then read
    # it into OpenCV format
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
    image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    # return the image
    return image


# initialize the list of image URLs to download
url="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/09/01/18/2BE1E88B00000578-3218613-image-m-5_1441127035222.jpg"

print ("downloading %s" % (url))
image = url_to_image(url)
cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

And the output is:
[image: the image displayed fetched from the given url]

Comment: This implementation fails on the target url. https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png